# Zend framework and APC cache CLI access

Tags: zend-framework, caching, command-line-interface, apc

I have a background job that is creating images.  My original plan was to have the job set an apc cache key value when the job is done.  I have a listener in my web app that pings this cache until it gets a value,

However, even though I have added enable.apc_cli to my php.ini, the fetch and save commands do nothing in my job.  There is no error, but no value is returned either.  APC works fine in my actual web app.

I have also tried using the zend cache factory with no luck.  I tried both apc and file.
Im about to attempt using redis for this but wanted to see if I could use File or APC caching first.

Im using Zend framework 1.11.11  and Zend CE

Any idea how to make apc work from the command line?   Also if there is a better solution for tracking job progress other than cache values, id be interested to hear that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same issue.  It isn't a zend framework problem, I imagine that the CLI is automagically sandboxed from the thread the webserver exists within.  Memcached works as expected.